# SSH Server on Ubuntu does not work

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I wanted to start SSH server on Ubuntu 14.04 running on VirtualBox. I installed Openssh, sshd, etc., configured `sshd_config` to listen on IP, which I see in `ifconfig` and it is not working. I am starting `sshd` on port 2222. `nmap <my-ip>` gives:

```
PORT        STATE        SERVICE
80/tcp        open        http
2222/tcp        open        EtherNet/IP-1
8080/tcp        open        http-proxy
```

HTTP server started at 8080 works fine, so why `sshd` service is not recognized? When I try to log in by `ssh` as a client I see 
"Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known".

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you provide the `-p 2222` to the ssh command?  Also what does `lsof :i 2222` say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what command are you using ?

```
ssh -p 2222 foobar
```

The error message you mention say that you do not resolv foobar. have you tried using IP ?

e.g.

```
ssh -p 2222 192.168.1.6
```

Additionally, if you want `nmap`to show what's actually running instead of resolving well-known ports to protocols, you can use the `-sV` [option](http://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html).

```
-sV: Probe open ports to determine service/version info
```

Comment: @val0x00ff: thanks! What a stupid mistake, I used ssh <ip>:<port> instead "-p <port".

Comment: @trivelt I'm starting to develop some supernatural abilities. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` isn't listed in your nmap output as `nmap` prints the well known service that uses the port it's found.  Port 2222 is normally used by the `EthernetIP` service which is used in industrial control.

The error message states `Could not resolve hostname`.  This means it can't find the server by name.  Try connecting using it's IP address instead, or alternatively, fix your name resolution using either DNS or adding the server to the file `/etc/hosts` on the client.  If your client is Windows, I believe the file is `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.